# Facebook JS SDK with Windows 8 - FB is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, facebook, windows-8

I'm creating an app for windows 8 that involves facebook integration. I know you can't load in external javascript so I stuck an iframe as the very first element which linked to a file that linked to the facebook sdk. My DOM explorer seems to tell me that that loads fine

Despite having a

```
$(document).ready(function() {
}
```

around my FB.login function (which is below `window.fbAsyncInit`), I'm being told that 'FB' is undefined.

Some notes:
- Login is only invoked after the user presses a button
- Works fine online
- My JS code..

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
    appId      : 'APP ID', // App ID
    channelUrl : '//url', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    frictionlessRequests : true, // enable frictionless requests        
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
 });

 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    ...
 }); 
}; 


function goLogIn() {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      ...
    }, {scope: 'user_photos,friends_photos,publish_stream',}); //FB.login
  });
}
```

Any ideas on why this is doing this? I'm presuming its to do with the order windows 8 processes things in..

Thanks,
Niall

Comment: $().ready is not going to help you here as there's no correlation between `fbAsyncInit` and the document being ready.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution on that...:) Windows 8 app would not load an external js file for you so what you need to do is go to http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js, download the file and load it locally. Hope this helps you.